# How to keep dynamically added CSS class on body

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm adding a css class on body tag with JS when a user clicks on an element. I want to keep this class when user navigates to a different page whiting the app.

I'm using templates and it seems my imported template containing the body tag gets re-rendered when navigating to a different page that also uses this template.

How can I keep dynamically added CSS class on body tag?

```
function init() {
$(".trigger").click(function(e) {
    $(document.body).addClass('someClass');
});
```

This is how I'm importing to other pages head and body tag

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
```

....

Comment: There are many options. You first have to decide where you are going to store the information about the user's choice. It can be in a cookie, in the session, in the data base... It can be associated with the currently logged in user, or with the current session, or even IP address.

Comment: I would recommend storing it in a cookie.